# Varios errores en PHP y SQL

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

Los errores:

> Query failed: ERROR: El operador no existe: character varying = integer
>
> LINE 2: WHERE rif_ben=12133937
>
> HINT:  Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos.

Otro error que tengo es el siguiente:

> Error: the XML response that was returned from the server is invalid

Codigo en *PHP*:

```
<?php
// Saldo por formato de viáticos pregunta si el saldo a rendir es mayor a 0
if ($salxrendir < 0) {
    return true;
    $salxrendir= saldoarendir*-1;
}else{
    $msj = 'no existe reintegro para su viatico';
}

// Selecciona de la base de datos con la condicion de rif_ben sea igual a la celdula del beneficiario
$query = " SELECT cta_x_pagar FROM tes_beneficiarios WHERE rif_ben=$rif_ben ";
$resultado = $db->execQuery($conn, $query);
if($resultado){
    $row_rif_ben = $resultado[0]; #Obtener Fila
    $rif_ben  = $rif_ben['cta_x_pagar'];
}

// Cuenta el número de consultas por el numero de solicitudes que hay
$query = "SELECT COUNT('nro_sol') FROM plan_solpago WHERE nro_sol=$nro_sol AND rif_ben=$rif ";
$sol = $db->execQuery($conn, $query);
if(count($sol) <= 0){   
    $msj = 'no hay solicitudes de pago hechas';
    return false;
}
else{
    $row_nro_sol = $sol[0]; #Obtener Fila
    $rif_ben  = $rif_ben['nro_sol'];
    $row_rif_ben = $sol[0]; #Obtener Fila
    $rif_ben  = $rif_ben['rif_ben'];
}
if($key == plan_solpago){
    $colsv = &$datosDetalle[$key];
    foreach ($colsv as &$row){

        $ano_pro     = row('ano_pro');
        $nro_sol     = row('nro_sol');
        $fecha_sol   = row('fecha_sol');
        $rif         = row('rif_ben');
        $concepto    = row('concepto');
        $mto_neto    = row('montoneto'); 
        $total_pagar = row('total_pagar');
        $vcod_ger    = row('cod_ger');
        $vusuario    = row('usuario'); 
        $vano_sol    = row('ano_sol');
        $vano_origen = row('ano_origen');
        $vrazon      = row('razon');

        $query = "INSERT INTO plan_solpago(ano_pro, nro_sol, fecha_sol, rif_ben, concepto,
        montoneto, , total_pagar, cod_ger, usuario,stag_reg,ano_sol,ano_origen,razon)VALUES($ano_pro,'$nro_sol','$fecha_sol','$rif',
        '$concepto','$mto_neto','$total_pagar','$vcod_ger','$stag_reg','$vusuario','$vano_pro','$vano_origen','$vrazon')";
        $res = $db->execQuery($conn, $query);
        if (!$res){
            $msj = 'Error insertando detalles de reintegro de rendicion de viactico en solicitud de pago';

            return false;
        }
    }

}
if($key == cxp_detcontablesolpago){
    $colsv = &$datosDetalle[$key];
    foreach ($colsv as &$row){
        $ano_pro = row('ano_pro');
        $ord_pag = row('ord_pag');
        $nro_ren = row('nro_ren');
        $tipo    = row('tipo');
        $gasto   = row('gasto');

        $query = "INSERT INTO cxp_detcontablesolpago(ano_pro, ord_pag,nro_ren,tipo,gasto)VALUES($ano_pro,'$ord_pag','$tipo','$nro_ren','$gasto') ";
        $res = $db->execQuery($conn, $query);
    }
}

// Insertamos los valores en la tabla detalles de gastos. Solicitud pago
if($key == cxp_detgastossolpago){
    $colsv = &$datosDetalle[$key];
    foreach ($colsv as &$row){
        $ano_pro      = row('ano_pro');
        $ord_pag      = row('ordpag');
        $status_presu = row('status_presu');

        $query = "INSERT INTO cxp_detgastossolpago(ano_pro, ord_pag, status_presu)" .
        "VALUES($ano_pro,'$ord_pag',$status_presu)";
        $res = $db->execQuery($conn, $query);
    }
}

// Actualizando la tabla correlativo de pagos
$query = "  UPDATE cxp_corrsolpago SET sol_pag WHERE flujo=$flujo AND ano_pro=$ano_fiscal AND sol_pago=$sol_pago" ;     
$resultado = $db->execQuery($conn,$query);
if(!$resultado){
    $msj = "Error Actualizando Correlativo de Solicitud de Pago para reintegro de Viacticos.";

    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: El mensaje de error *`...el operador no existe: character varying = integer...`* hace pensar que la columna `rif_ben` es del tipo `VARCHAR` y estás intentando compararla como si fuera del tipo `INTEGER`. ¿De qué tipo es esa columna realmente? Si  es `VARCHAR` tienes que usar comillas simples en la comparación: `$query="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE rif_ben='$rif_ben' ";`

Comment: Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/329420/edit) indicando cuál es el problema y qué es lo que intentas lograr y agregando en qué líneas aparecen los errores.

Comment: Tal cual el primer problema se resuelve con lo que puso @A.Cedano y es probable que el segundo error también sea resuelto "por inercia", si los mensajes de error los tienes configurado para que se muestren en pantalla el primer error provoca salidas indeseadas que tu XML parser no lo puede interpretar.